Compute $\varepsilon(\delta)$ of the Analytic Gaussian Mechanism
Let $q : X^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a deterministic function with global $L_2$ sensitivity $\Delta=\sup_{x\simeq x'\in X^n}\Vert q(x)-q(x')\Vert_2$. Define the Gaussian mechanism $M : X^n \to \mathbb{R}$ by $M(x) = \mathcal{N}(q(x), \sigma^2)$ for some $\sigma^2 > 0$. Then, for any $\varepsilon \geq 0$, $M$ satisfies $(\varepsilon, \delta)$-DP with
$$ \delta = \overline{\Phi}\left(\frac{\varepsilon - \rho_*}{\sqrt{2\rho_*}}\right) 
- e^\varepsilon \cdot \overline{\Phi}\left(\frac{\varepsilon + \rho_*}{\sqrt{2\rho_*}}\right), $$
where $\rho_* := \Delta^2 / 2\sigma^2$ and $\overline{\Phi}(z) := 
\mathbb{P}_{G \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)}[G > z] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_z^\infty \exp(-t^2/2) \, \mathrm{d}t$.
The above theorem regards $\delta$ as a function of $\varepsilon$. The question is whether we can reverse this process and calculate the corresponding $\varepsilon$ given $\delta$. The solution can be either analytical or numerical.

Why don't you define $(\epsilon,\delta)-$ sensitivity for completeness?

@kodlu Thanks for the reminder, the definition has been added.

Sorry, I don't see an explicit definition, probably my problem. What is the exact probability which is bounded by $\delta$ given $\varepsilon$?
